# PyQt communication between different class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wanted to share data between two layouts (two classes in my case) in PyQt5.

How can I connect one layout action to the layout of another class properly?
For example every time I click on the button on class Left, the spinbox, on class Right, increases.

```py
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        generalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        left = Left()
        right = Right()

        generalLayout.addLayout(left)
        generalLayout.addLayout(right)
        self.setLayout(generalLayout)

class Left(QVBoxLayout):
    signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("+ 1")
        button.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.addWidget(button)

    def add(self):
        self.signal.emit()

class Right(QVBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        spinbox = QSpinbox()
        self.addWidget(spinbox)
        # spinbox.connect(???) ???

def main():
    mainApp = QApplication([])
    mainWindow = Main()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(mainApp.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I subscribe to the left signal inside my right class?

Maybe there is another feature like in the web app with subject and observer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanna catch the signal and bind it to your right component (to a function for instance) so that when the signal is thrown, it will call the appropriate function

An example :

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__()
            generalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
            centralWidget = QWidget()
            centralWidget.setLayout(generalLayout)
            self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
    
            left = Left()
            right = Right() 
            left.signal.connect(right.increment_spinbox_size) // connect left signal to a funcction inside right that will increase the size of the spinbox
            generalLayout.addLayout(left)
            generalLayout.addLayout(right)
            self.setLayout(generalLayout)

class Right(QVBoxLayout):
        def __init__(self, initial_value):
            super().__init__()
            self.spinbox = QSpinBox()
            self.addWidget(self.spinbox)
    
        def increment_spinbox_size(self):
            current_value = self.spinbox.value()
            self.spinbox.setValue(current_value + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your report. However, if I have a deep nested widget, is it still relevant ? So in Main you will have something like left.signal.connect(right.top.bottom.test.widget.increment_spinbox_size) ?

Comment: Well you pretty much have no other choice than connecting the signal to the widget (That's the standard way of doing it)
But if you happen to have a dependency between such nested object, you may ask yourself if your architecture is coherent? I think it's a nice question to ask yourself

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong in doing something like `left.signal.connect(right.top.bottom.whatever.cow.banana)`. But it's *conceptually* wrong (and awful to read or debug). Consider the aspect of [encapsulation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)): an object should only provide access to its own methods, not those of its members; if you want to access a member of an object, that object should expose a method to do it: the object acts as a "proxy" for the member (eg. `left.signal.connect(right.banana)`). See [this related answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/70697665).

Answer (score 0):

I used the trigger function in the parent main class to call another function, which will change the values of the declared class off the second window, from that I have access to variables from another file. It is necessary to import your Second file.py

main.py file:

```
from Settings import Variables #Important to import your file.py of new window to access variables from there.

class CSettings(QMainWindow): #I created the widget class before the function of the main class, which will refer to the new Window.
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CSettings, self).__init__(parent)


        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()  
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


class MWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.Parent)

        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)

        Settings_btn = QAction('⌬', self)  #create an example button
        Settings_btn.triggered.connect(self.Settings) #importantly, the lambda function will be called when I click the button and it will call the Settings function.
        navbar.addAction(Settings_btn)

        self.show()


    def Settings(self):
    Variables.needExit=False #From here I can access and define variables from another .py file in the case Settings.py
```

Settings.py file:

```
class Variables(object): #The class that contains the variable.

    needExit=False


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    
      the remainder of the code...
```